# Android Override Explicit Intent

Tags: android, overriding, android-activity, android-intent, explicit

My app needs to have a `intent-filter` that responds to a `Intent` that has it's component set (a explicit intent.) Here is a example.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.compareeverywhere","com.compareeverywhere.ScanActivity");
startActivity(i);
```

Just a simple `intent-filter` will not do - because the `Intent` is made for a specific component (`Activity`,) it just launches that without looking for intents at all. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks, Isaac Waller
P.S: Please don't reply "No."

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve Isaac. Could you try and explain further what you need the Intent-Filter to do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

:) That being said, imagine what would happen if Android allowed people to hijack Intents for specific components. Don't like a competitor's app? Just have yours hijack his main Activity with your own to display porn. Intents can specify specific components specifically because the authors don't want others to be able to replace them.

You have two options. If this is your own code, replace it with a generic intent, or if it belongs to someone else, contact them, and ask nicely for them to change it to a generic intent along with some good reasons why that is necessary.